# Named Router Outlet- I need to active the both multiple outlets Using angularv17.0^.0^(main outlet + 2 named Outlets)

Tags: html, angular, dom, angular-ui-router, angular17

**Problem  : - The second named router outlet(chat Area) in the router module is not rendering but the URL works fine.**

The UI idea is inspired from the vscode.

which is : - the icons from the left side is the main nav bar based on the link the user click, assume the user click on the `file Explore` icon the aside which next to the icon nav bar renders the files and this step is working fine for me in the `user` path when it's under the children of main route, after that the use click on any file the file would open/render in the editor area (which is here as `chatArea`).

> if I give the route like this the url would be some thin like this
> localhost:4200/(aside:users/(chatArea:chat/234562345634560987452745820404529487)
> Above URL is the example of the url.

JYI : I'm not using the SSR or common routing like just using the router outlet, because I learning angular so I need to know these stuffs.

**This below code snippet is my router Module**

```
import { Component, Inject, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppHomeComponent } from './pages/main/app-main.component';
import { UserListComponent } from './components/user-list/user-list.component';
// import { UserGroupListComponent } from './components/user-group-list/user-group-list.component';
import { UserGroupListComponent } from '../app/components/user-group-list/user-group-list.component';
import { ChatMessagesComponent } from './components/chat-messages/chat-messages.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './pages/signup/signup.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './pages/login/login.component';
import { SignupService } from './pages/signup/signup.service';
import { authGuard, singupLoginGuard } from './auth-guard.guard';
import { ChatAreaComponent } from './components/chat-area/chat-area.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {

    path: '',
    component: AppHomeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'users',
        component: UserListComponent,
        outlet: "aside",
      },
      {
        path: 'groups',
        component: UserGroupListComponent,
        outlet: "aside",

      },

    ],
    canActivate: [authGuard]
  },
  {
    path: "chat/:userKey",
    component: ChatAreaComponent,
    outlet: "chatArea"
  },
  {
    path: 'signup',
    component: SignupComponent,
    canActivate: [singupLoginGuard] // if the user reached the root path then they should not access the signup page or login page using the can active guard by a variable called userCurrentlyLoggedin = false then swtich it t the true after user logged in
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    canActivate: [singupLoginGuard]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: "/",
    pathMatch: "full"
  },


];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{enableTracing:true})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**This is the userList Component which is rendered in the aside tag and outlet**

```
<div class="flex flex-col w-full h-full gap-2 md:w-full">

  <div
    class="usercardlist   w-full h-auto rounded-md cursor-pointer select-none  text-white  p-[0.2rem] hover:bg-gray-700
      hover:bg-opacity-50 flex justify-start gap-1 items-center "
    *ngFor="let user of userList;index as i">
    <!-- Group Profile pic -->

    <app-userprofile [name]="user.fullName"></app-userprofile>
    <a
    [routerLink]="[{outlets:{chatArea:['chat',user.userKey]}}]">
    <!-- (click)="establishSocket(user.userKey)" -->
    {{user.userName}}
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
<!-- bg-gray-700 text-white hover:text-black p-[0.2rem] hover:bg-sky-100  -->
```

**This is my main layout**

```
<div id="mainlayout" class="grid w-screen h-screen overflow-hidden">

  <app-action-center class="w-12"></app-action-center>

  <aside
    class="flex flex-col justify-start w-screen h-screen p-2 overflow-y-auto bg-background-200 md:w-auto lg:w-auto">
    <app-search></app-search>
    <router-outlet name="aside"></router-outlet>
  </aside>

  <main
    class="relative hidden overflow-auto lg:block md:block bg-background-100">
    <!-- <app-chat-area></app-chat-area> -->
    <router-outlet name="chatArea"></router-outlet>
  </main>
</div>
```

I need an solution to solve this component not rendering,
I think the issue cause by the main/primary router outlet because the outlet's are active a single link at a time? or maybe I think so? .

I need help on this, kindly consider this as valid doubt/confusion.

Thanks in advance.